# if mysql_query() fails, what to do?

Tags: php, mysql, security

Sometimes so happens that mysql_query() fails to INSERT data and I am unaware of it. So, the question is how do I know when it happens?

Comment: I don't think this question deserves downvotes. It's basic, but it's reasonably well-phrased and the answers so far have been sincere. You jerkfaces from Pod Six need to cut it out.

Answer (score 11):

Quoting the documentation page of [`mysql_query`](http://fr.php.net/mysql_query) :

> For `SELECT`, `SHOW`, `DESCRIBE`, `EXPLAIN`
> and other statements returning
> resultset, `mysql_query()` returns a
> `resource` on success, or `FALSE` on
> error.
>
> For other type of SQL statements,
> `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE`, `DROP`, etc,
> `mysql_query()` returns `TRUE` on
> success or `FALSE` on error.

So, to detect whether there's been an error or not, you have to test the return value of your call to `mysql_query` :

```
$result = mysql_query('...');
if ($result === false) {
    // And error has occured while executing
    // the SQL query
}
```

Then, what can you do ?

- Well, first, you can log the error to a file, that you can analyse later

  - For than, you can use [`mysql_error`](https://www.php.net/mysql_error) and [`mysql_errno`](https://www.php.net/mysql_errno).
- And you can display a nice error message the user

  - i.e. some kind of "*oops, an error occured page*".

Remember, though : the user doesn't need to know *(and will not understand)* the technical error message -- so don't display it.

Comment: You should definitely use mysql_error() if you get a query failing. It's not always terrible helpful, particularly if you have a large query. But it may help you to diagnose what the problem may be.

Answer (score 3):

You can use mysql_error [php.net/mysql_error](http://php.net/mysql_error) to get a better explanation that you then either display or log it in a file.

Answer (score 3):

One check that I usually do is like in the example

```
$result = mysql_query( $query );
if ( !empty( $error = mysql_error() ) )
{
    echo 'Mysql error '. $error ."<br />\n";
}
else
{
    // the query ran successfully
}
```

This is a good check for any kind of queries

Comment: nice touch, but in production you don't want that because the SQL-injection crowd will know how to exploit your weaknesses that much easier.

Answer (score 1):

suggest making a wrapper for mysql_query that detects failure and logs the query plus mysql_error somewhere

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a sensible client library, it will throw an exception when a SQL command fails, and you can examine the error code programmatically to know what to do.

If you have no code handling that specific error path, you should probably run a standard error handler which logs the error, stack trace and some other debug info into a log.

Answer (score 0):

you have to analyze your sql. did you escape your parameters? sounds like this could be the problem. you may paste your sql so we can help you.

for showing the error, you can eg.

```
$result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error());
```

.

Comment: While this is a good answer to identifying what caused the failure, I don't think this is answering what the OP is asking.  I think the OP wants to know how to determine when it fails, not what could cause it to fail.

Answer (score 0):

If the cause of the error is deadlock, you might want to try again.

Answer (score 0):

You can check how many rows MySQL has inserted/updated/deleted by doing this query right after your insert/update/delete query.

```
SELECT ROW_COUNT() as rows_affected
```

If this returns `0` your insert failed. If it returns `1` or more you've succeeded.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_row-count

Answer (score -2):

Probably you can check LAST_INSERT_ID() (mysql_insert_id() in PHP). Provided that your table has auto_increment column.

Comment: if mysql_insert_id() returns 0 and your table has an auto_increment column, then the last INSERT was failed. i would prefer mysql_error, though.

Comment: -1, last_insert_id() will show you the insert number from the previous insert in (possibly another) table if this insert failed. Not meaningful in any way whatsoever.